# SharpSvn marks file as missing but I need deleted

Tags: c#, .net, svn, sharpsvn

I want to delete file in svn. 
I do this so:

```
svnClient.Delete( pathToFile, new SvnDeleteArgs {Force = true} );
```

When I want to commit chenges, in svn file status is 'missing', but I need 'deleted'.
What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I passed on the path to lowercase.
For SVN it is important that the file name was in the same register as in the repository.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as accepted to help others with a similar problem in the future

Comment: You can use SvnTools.GetTruePath() or GetNormalizedTruePath() to help you find the right/true casing of a file/directory.