# Cannot delete file using SharpSvn: {filepath} is not a working copy

Tags: sharpsvn

I am unable to delete a file from SVN using SharpSvn.

Here is my code:

```cs
using (SvnClient client = new SvnClient())
{
    // snip...
    string filePath = "C:\\path\\to\\file.txt";
    client.Delete(filePath, deleteArgs);
}
```

Here is the exception:

> SharpSvn.SvnInvalidNodeKindException: ''C:\path\to\file.txt' is not a working copy'

I confirmed this filepath exists and is tied to SVN. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2910866) led me to the answer. I was using the incorrect casing in my filepath. Following the example above, maybe I tried to delete the file "C:\path\to\file.txt" but the actual path on disk was "C:\PATH\TO\file.txt". I fixed by using `SvnTools.GetTruePath`:

```cs
client.Delete(SvnTools.GetTruePath(filePath), deleteArgs);
```